# Not able to click on an element in Appium

Tags: android

[My UI Automator Viewer Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AkVrx.png)

I want to click on Play Now button and tried the following code:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.view.View[contains(@content-desc,'Play Now')]"));
```

and this code:

```
driver.findElement(By.name("Play Now!"));
```

These codes are not showing any error but not clicking on Play Now button even.

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

try this one

```
driver.findElementByAccessibilityId("content written on the button").click();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you feel your Xpath is right but you are not click on that means that is because of synchronization problem. Just give time to find the element and click. Try like below example

```
Thread.sleep(5000);

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.view.View[contains(@content-desc,'Play Now')]")).click();
```

`Thread.sleep(5000)` gives 5 second time to search for the element. This should work in your case.
if click works fine not need to use any waits.
You can further use implicit or explicit wait once you are perfect with your automation.